# when i want save data by using CoreData Getting error like The Model used to Open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vcJV.png)

when i want save data by using CoreData Getting error like The Model used to Open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store

For More Details See Image

Answer (score 1):

D ramana,

Your device/simulator might be having the older instance of the app and you must have modified the data model of coredata without creating the version of coredata model.

**Solution:**

Uninstall the existing app instance re-run should work fine :)

**Tip :**

This can be a serious issue if you move your product to market and modify the data model without creating the version and re-release the updated version of the app. All your users will have this crash untill and unless they uninstall and re-install it.

Consider creating the versions of coredata models before modifying the existing data model.